# Реализация динамического массива на java

Tags: java

Как создать свой динамический массив на **Java**, с использованием `SET`?

Comment: Vector ? :)

ps: И что конкретно у вас не получается ? Уточните вопрос, иначе вопрос сводится к решению учебного задания

Comment: @aaaaa1aaaaa, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: С одной стороны я понимаю, что автор получил задание самостоятельно реализовать класс DynamicArray, с другой уверен, что для его образования будет более полезно просмотреть исходный код java.util.Vector. 

Какие есть мнения ?

Comment: @Андрей, @shurik Vector - устаревший класс, вместо него рекомендуется использовать ArrayList. Часть комментария из исходников ArrayList от Oracle

>This class is roughly equivalent to Vector, except that it is unsynchronized.

Не всегда надо верить авторам книжек, часто желаемое (обещанное менеджерами разработчиков) выдается за действительное.

Comment: Наоборот, у методов Vector есть синхронизация. [Исходники, если интересно](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Vector.java.html). ArrayList там же рядом.

Comment: @Андрей, переведу, "Этот (ArrayList) класс приблизительно похож на Vector-класс, за исключением того, что он не синхронизирован". 

Вам бы многое стало понятно, загляни вы в код, который дал @avp по ссылке. Становится ясно, например то, что оба эти класса, как минимум, унаследованы от одного и того же класса - `AbstractList`, а так же реализуют один и тот же набор интерфейсов `Cloneable, List, Serializable, RandomAccess, Collection`.

И разница выделена в самом верху описания `ArrayList` - "Note that this implementation is not synchronized."

Comment: @Андрей, извините, я невнимательно прочел Ваш вопрос. @Dex уже ответил. Vector синхронизироан, в многопоточной программе использовать его. Или разумно синхронизировать что надо самому. IMHO последнее всегда лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Эти статьи: [первая](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) и [вторая](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) могут Вам помочь.

Comment: Чем? Там кроме оценки времени выполнения алгоритмов собственно ничего полезного и нет.

Comment: @ReinRaus обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Set предназначен для хранения уникальных элементов, посему использовать его в этом случае нецелесообразно. Лучше использовать List для хранения данных.

Если проанализировать функционал, то можно выделить следующие ключевые функции массива:

1. возможность создать массив любого типа
2. возможность указать размерность массива
3. возможность для каждого элемента получить значение и изменить значение
4. возможность изменять размерность массива (явно или автоматически)

В результате получается что-то эдакое:

```
class TestArray<E>
{
   private List < E > list = null;

   public TestArray ( final int size )
   {
      this.list = new ArrayList < E > ();

      // инициализируем все поля значениями по умолчанию (по аналогии с массивом)
      for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
      {
         list.add ( null );
      }
   }

   public E get ( final int index )
   {
      return list.get ( index );
   }

   public void set ( final int index, final E value )
   {
      list.set ( index, value );
   }

   /* вот здесь начинается самое интересное, если вам нужен массив статической
      размерности тогда надо обьявлять этот метод public и вызывать его явно из кода.
      в случае с динамическим массивом этот метод должен вызыватся автоматически 
      из метода set. его задача не только изменить размерность массива, 
      но так же следить за тем чтоб данные сохранялись при resize. 
      впрочем если сделать его приватным тогда ваш массив сможет только увиличиватся,
      но не уменьшатся, что тоже нелогично :) */
   void resize (int size) {...}

   @Override
   public String toString ()
   {
      return list.toString ();
   }
}
```

Вот вам и минимальная реализация, можете добавить любой нужный вам функционал.

Comment: Ваш класс кажется просто является оберткой для ArrayList.

Comment: я не запрещаю автору использовать свою реализацию list. я считаю такой вариант более прост для восприятия

Comment: Но ведь еще более простой вариант
    
    class TestArray extends ArrayList {
        /* дополнительный функционал */
    }

Comment: Уважаемые, вы вопрос читали? Человека не интересует ArrayList. Ему нужно использовать `Set<E>`.

Comment: я думаю проблема не в ответах а в вопросах, - нехватает метки учебное задание. позже поправлю ответ